# Hide/Show a Column based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I'm trying to hide a column and to show a column with two different excel-VBA(s)
My code for hiding is working fine but when I'm unable to recall the column the VBA button just blink and do nothing. The possible reason is when I try to show the column it is not available due to hidden. What changes should I do so that it read hidden column too?

```
Sub SHOW()
Dim rngX1 As Range

    Set rngX1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:P4").Find(Range("G1"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngX1 Is Nothing Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to delete Column     " & Range("G1"), vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    rngX1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could update this question with a screenshot of example data... it is not clear what the issue with your code is in isolation of an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Find() to locate content in a hidden column. You could use Match instead.

Untested:

```
Sub SHOW()
    Dim m, sht
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    m = Application.Match(Range("G1"), sht.Range("A4:P4"), 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to delete Column     " & _
                              Range("G1"), vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sht.Columns(m).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```